# Can somebody check my proof of this theorem about the derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I proved the following theorem and would greatly appreciate it if someone could check my proof:

Theorem: Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ be differentiable and $\alpha$ such that $f'(a) < \alpha < f'(b)$ (or $f'(a) > \alpha > f'(b)$ ) then there exists $c\in (a,b)$ with $f'(c) = \alpha$

Proof: Define a map $g:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ , $x \mapsto f(x) - x \alpha$. This map is continuous. Therefore $g$ attains a minimum on $[a,b]$. Let $c$ be in $[a,b]$ with the property that $g(c) = \min_x g(x)$. If $c=a$ (or $c=b$) then $g(a) = f(a) -a\alpha \le g(x) = f(x) - x\alpha$   and therefore for all $x \in [a,b]$:

${f(a)-f(x)\over a - x} \ge \alpha > f'(a) = \lim_{x \to a}{f(a) - f(x) \over a-x}$.

As this holds for all $ x\in [a,b]$ it follows that

$\lim_{x\to a}{f(a)-f(x)\over a - x} \ge \alpha > f'(a) = \lim_{x \to a}{f(a) - f(x) \over a-x}$ which is a contradiction. Similarly derive a contradiction for $c=b$. Therefore $c \in (a,b)$. But if $g$ attains an extremum on $(a,b)$ then $g'(c)=0$ and hence $f'(c) = \alpha$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thank you. No, I don't have a previous result. I am trying to prove that it can't occur at $a$ or $b$.

Comment: @DavidMitra I corrected the inequality and the minimum. Is the proof correct now?

Comment: @DavidMitra I am not sure: are you suggesting to replace the argument with the limit in my proof by this $g(y) < g(a)$ argument?

Comment: Yes, it looks correct now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [Darboux's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29)

One point that is false : you divide by $a-x$ but this is negative so you must change the inequality.

This leads to $\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a} <= \alpha$. Take a look at the min of $f(x)-x\alpha$ similarly to complete the proof

Comment: Why the downvote? Can the downvote please explain.

Comment: @newb Thanks for reaching out, I don't know either, if you want to help with that you can accept my answer / upvote (I posted even before the direct smaller comments)